# image file not being written to sd card

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an image file to a directory on my sd card and it doesn't appear to be working.  When I read the image into the bytearray it does not write the contents to the sd card. The code is as follows:

```
public void addRecord(){

        long id;

        out =  new ByteArrayOutputStream(128);
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

          File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
          File dir = new File(sdCard + File.separator + "studentpics");

          if(!dir.exists()){

          dir.mkdir();  

            }

          File f = new File(sdCard + File.separator + dir.toString() + File.separator +  strStudentName + ".png");

          try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(out.toByteArray());

            fos.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
File f = new File(sdCard + File.separator + dir.toString() + File.separator +  strStudentName + ".png");
```

With

```
File f = new File( dir.toString() + File.separator +  strStudentName + ".png");
```

Comment: This might be the reason (sdCard.toString() being called), however, a better way to do it would be to do `File pics = new File(sdCard, "studentPics");`, and for the other one `File picture = new File(pics, strStudentName + ".png");`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to request permission to write to the external storage. Try adding this line to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```